# Fluent Validator .Net Core Injection Dependency Not Working

Tags: validation, inheritance, dependency-injection, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I am trying to validate a derived class and I also want to validate the base class. This is the code, and I have the following error on EmployeeValidator Constructor:

**There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'personRepository' of 'PersonValidator.PersonValidator'**

```cs
    public class Person
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public int IDCard  { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeRecord { get; set; }

    }

    public class PersonValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T> where T : Person
    {
        public PersonValidator(IPersonRepository personRepository)
        {
            RuleFor(b => b.FullName).NotNull();

            RuleFor(x => x)
            .Must(x => !personRepository.ExistsIDCard(x.IDCard))
            .WithErrorCode("IDCardAlreadyExist");
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeValidator : PersonValidator<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeValidator(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
        {
            RuleFor(d => d.Position).NotNull();

            RuleFor(x => x)
            .Must(x => !employeeRepository.ExistsEmployeeRecord(x.EmployeeRecord))
            .WithErrorCode("EmployeeRecordAlreadyExist");
        }
    }
```

What would be the appropriate way to validated EmployeeValidator using FluentValidation framework without duplicating rules for fields of Base class (Person)?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `base` constructor and pass `IPersonRepository` to it

```cs
public class EmployeeValidator : PersonValidator<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidator(IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository, IPersonRepository personRepository) 
        : base(personRepository)
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.Position).NotNull();

        RuleFor(x => x)
        .Must(x => !employeeRepository.ExistsEmployeeRecord(x.EmployeeRecord))
        .WithErrorCode("EmployeeRecordAlreadyExist");
    }
}
```